# Issue with getname() and addmemberlist()

Tags: java, class, methods

For some reason my `getName()` method and and `addMemberList()` is not working.

I have tried everything parsing and debugging with a friend but nothing seems to work.

main

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

      initialUserGuide();
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("familytree.txt"));
      Family fr = new Family(sc);
      fr.displayAllMembersList();
      processUserInput(fr);

}

   static void initialUserGuide(){
  System.out.println("The input file consists of names of all Humans");
 System.out.println("Enter the Human name from below list, to display his/her maternal line, Paternal line and children");
      }

      static void processUserInput(Family fr)
      {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      Person person;
          System.out.println("newt Human ( enter told " + "quit)?");
          String nextLine = input.nextLine();
          while(nextLine.length() > 0){
          person = fr.find(nextLine);
          if(person == null)
          System.out.println("NoMatch Occured");
          else
          {
              displayMaternalLine(person);
              displayPaternalLine(person);
              displayChildren(person);
          }
              System.out.println("");
              System.out.println("next Human (enter to quit)?");
              nextLine = input.nextLine();
          }
      }

      static void displayMaternalLine(Person mother)
      {
          System.out.println("Maternal Line");
          int i = 0;
          int count = 1;
          while(mother != null)
          {
          for(i = 0;i < count; i++){
              System.out.println("");
          }
              System.out.println(mother.getName());
              mother = mother.getMother();
              count++;
          }
      }

      static void displayPaternalLine(Person father)
      {
       System.out.println("Paternal Line");
          int i = 0;
          int count = 1;
          while(father != null)
          {
          for(i = 0;i < count; i++){
              System.out.println("");
          }
              System.out.println(father.getName());
              father = father.getMother();
              count++;
          }
      }

      static void displayChildren(Person person)
      {
          System.out.println("Children");
          ArrayList ptr = person.getChildren();

          if(ptr.size()==0)
          {
              System.out.println(" none");
          }

          for(int i = 0; i < ptr.size(); i++)
          {
              System.out.println("\t" + ptr.get(i).getName());
          }

      }






       }
```

Family class

```
package assignment7;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Family{
    private ArrayList allMembersList;

    public Family(Scanner sc){
    allMembersList = new ArrayList();
    addAllMembersList(sc);
    makeParentChildRelation(sc);

    }

    Person find(String name)
    {
    for(int i = 0; i < allMembersList.size();i++)
    {
    if(allMembersList.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
        return (Person) allMembersList.get(i);

    }
    return null;

    }

    public void addAllMembersList(Scanner sc){
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    while(line.length() != 0)
    {
    Person person = new Person(line);
    addMembersList.add(person);
    line = sc.nextLine();
    }
    }

    public void makeParentChildRelation(Scanner sc)
    {
    String nextLine;

    String name,motherName,fatherName;

    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
    name = sc.nextLine();
    motherName = sc.nextLine();
    fatherName = sc.nextLine();
    Person personn = find(name);

    if(!motherName.equals("unknown"))
    {
        Person mother = find(motherName);
    personn.setMother(mother);
    mother.addChildren(personn);
    }

    if(!fatherName.equals("unknown"))
    {
        Person father = find(fatherName);
    personn.setFather(father);
    father.addChildren(personn);
    }
    }
    }

    public void displayAllMembersList()
    {
    for(int i = 0; i < allMembersList.size(); i++)
    {
    Person person = (Person) allMembersList.get(i);
        System.out.println(person.getName());

    }
    }
}
```

Person class

```
package assignment7;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Person mother;
    private Person father;
    private ArrayList children;


    public Person(String name)
    {
    this.name = name;
    children = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setFather(Person Father){
        this.father = Father;

    }

     public void setMother(Person Mother){
        this.mother = Mother;

    }

     public void addChildren(Person Child)
     {

     children.add(Child);
     }

     public String getName()
     {
     return this.name;
     }

     public Person getFather()
     {
       return this.father;
     }
     public Person getMother()
     {
         return this.mother;
     }

     public ArrayList getChildren(){
     return this.children;

     }
}
```

familytree.txt

Maternal line:
    Henry VIIII
        Elizabeth of York
Paternal line:
    Henry VIII
        Henry VII
Children:
    Mary I
    Elizabeth I
    Edward VI

Any help would be greatly appreciated here is the original problem.

Write a family database program. Create a class to represent a person and to store references to the person's mother, father, and any children the person has. Read a file of names to initialize the name and parent-child relationships of each Person. Store the overall list of Persons as an Arraylist. Write an overall main user interface that asks for a name and prints the maternal and paternal family line for that person.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using generic ArrayList to store List of Person objects. You should use `List<Person>`.
Also, `addMembersList` should be `allMembersList` (must be a typo).

Here is working code.

```
//main

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        initialUserGuide();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("familytree.txt"));
        Family fr = new Family(sc);
        fr.displayAllMembersList();
        processUserInput(fr);


    }

    static void initialUserGuide() {
        System.out.println("The input file consists of names of all Humans");
        System.out.println("Enter the Human name from below list, to display his/her maternal line, Paternal line and children");
    }

    static void processUserInput(Family fr) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Person person;
        System.out.println("newt Human ( enter told " + "quit)?");
        String nextLine = input.nextLine();
        while (nextLine.length() > 0) {
            person = fr.find(nextLine);
            if (person == null)
                System.out.println("NoMatch Occured");
            else {
                displayMaternalLine(person);
                displayPaternalLine(person);
                displayChildren(person);
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("next Human (enter to quit)?");
            nextLine = input.nextLine();
        }
    }

    static void displayMaternalLine(Person mother) {
        System.out.println("Maternal Line");
        int i = 0;
        int count = 1;
        while (mother != null) {
            for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println(mother.getName());
            mother = mother.getMother();
            count++;
        }
    }

    static void displayPaternalLine(Person father) {
        System.out.println("Paternal Line");
        int i = 0;
        int count = 1;
        while (father != null) {
            for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println(father.getName());
            father = father.getMother();
            count++;
        }
    }

    static void displayChildren(Person person) {
        System.out.println("Children");
        List<Person> ptr = person.getChildren();

        if (ptr.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println(" none");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ptr.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("\t" + ptr.get(i).getName());
        }

    }


}


//Family

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Family {
    private List<Person> allMembersList;

    public Family(Scanner sc) {
        allMembersList = new ArrayList<>();
        addAllMembersList(sc);
        makeParentChildRelation(sc);

    }

    Person find(String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < allMembersList.size(); i++) {
            if (allMembersList.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                return (Person) allMembersList.get(i);

        }
        return null;

    }

    public void addAllMembersList(Scanner sc) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        while (line.length() != 0) {
            Person person = new Person(line);
            allMembersList.add(person);
            line = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }

    public void makeParentChildRelation(Scanner sc) {
        String nextLine;

        String name, motherName, fatherName;

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            name = sc.nextLine();
            motherName = sc.nextLine();
            fatherName = sc.nextLine();
            Person personn = find(name);

            if (!motherName.equals("unknown")) {
                Person mother = find(motherName);
                personn.setMother(mother);
                mother.addChildren(personn);
            }

            if (!fatherName.equals("unknown")) {
                Person father = find(fatherName);
                personn.setFather(father);
                father.addChildren(personn);
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayAllMembersList() {
        for (int i = 0; i < allMembersList.size(); i++) {
            Person person = (Person) allMembersList.get(i);
            System.out.println(person.getName());

        }
    }
}


//Person

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Person mother;
    private Person father;
    private List<Person> children;


    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setFather(Person Father) {
        this.father = Father;

    }

    public void setMother(Person Mother) {
        this.mother = Mother;

    }

    public void addChildren(Person Child) {

        children.add(Child);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Person getFather() {
        return this.father;
    }

    public Person getMother() {
        return this.mother;
    }

    public List<Person> getChildren() {
        return this.children;

    }
}
```